# Is it possible to move a windows frame or application frame by frame?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

**OCD QUESTION**

**The Example:**
I have this application open on my desktop: Application when first opened

[image]

When I open this particular application, I like to have it in the far right hand corner on my second monitor.

**Like this:** Application after manually moved

[image]

**The Description:**

I want to know if you can move an application frame by frame so that when I move one into the corner like that, I can move it without my shaky hands preventing me from lining the application properly. (I am aware of the keyboard shortcut for moving between displays such as: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>&<kbd>→</kbd>).

**This is what I do not like:** Application while struggling to move with shaky hands

[image]

(Where the background is showing to the top and right of the application)

**The Question**
Is there another keyboard shortcut for moving applications, essentially, frame by frame, or something of the like? I have searched quite a bit on the inter-webs and cannot find anything for this specific issue. (**For example:** If you are using an application such as PowerPoint, and you insert a picture you can use <kbd>←</kbd>&<kbd>→</kbd> to move the picture left and right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not see the screenshots right now, but are you looking for something like this:

- Inside a window which is not maximized, press <kbd>ALT</kbd> +
  <kbd>Space</kbd>, then <kbd>m</kbd> to **move**.
- Inside a window which is maximized the you first **restore** it using
  the same menu <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

Comment: This is essentially what I was looking for, yes. Unfortunately, I am guessing because of my display settings or something similar, this particular application that I have used as an example moves too far (once close to the edge) when using this method. However, this is what I wanted. Thank-you.

Comment: @MagnetM Glad I could help...BTW you are using windows right ?? You dont need  need to move and adjust the window with shaky hands in windows...you can simply left click on the application and move the mouse to drag it into the right or left corner of the screen and it will itself get properly aligned in the corner although I am not sure of this particular application but windows applications will get resized/aligned automatically when you move the cursor to the corner.

Comment: @MagnetM Windows 7/8 only allows to drag a window to the right or left edge of the screen but windows 10 allows to drag to the two edges as well as all the four corners of the screen.

Comment: I know exactly what you are referring to, as I do that with many other windows and applications. I am using windows 10, but this particular application will not work like some others. I guess I will just have to suck it up, and either move it manually to where I want it or just be unsatisfied.

Comment: @MagnetM yeah it saves a lot of time...windows 10 is awesome and very underrated ..anyways good luck.